# Archived Chatter Group Trail

Tags: chatter

I have an Archived chatter group which was activated. Now how I am supposed to find out who archived in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking in the Audit Setup Trail I couldn't find anything related to Chatter Group but on the Salesforce site I found below piece of information that gave me the answer.

> Salesforce runs a weekly review of feed activity in groups. If a group
> has no new feed posts or comments for 90 consecutive days, the group
> is archived automatically.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.collab_group_archiving.htm&type=5